# android-How to add bottom border like this

Tags: android, textview, android-styles

I want to add a bottom border to my textView , something like this :

[image]

could you help me to do so ? I don't want to use 9patch png ,is it possible to do so by using xml drawable?

Comment: you mean top,  not bottom?

Comment: @pskink , bottom or top no different ,How can I add this border to my view?

Comment: nine patches are designed to do such effect,  try them, i don't know why you don't want them...

Answer (score 3):

you can do it using layer list:

border.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/WhiteSmoke"/>
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:bottom="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Where you can define how thick the border is in android:left,right,..

To use it on text view you must save it into res/drawable and then set the background of your text view to:

```
android:background:"@drawable/border"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `nine-patch` to add such shadow, use the one attached here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `android:layout_alignParentBottom` attribute has to be declared in an element of the RelativeLayout.

Here is the sample code -

```
<RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
  <ListView ...>
  <Button android:id="@+id/btnGetMoreResults"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
   android:text="Get more"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

HOpe this helps :)

Comment: You didn't get what I mean , I want to add border not aligning views